# Refresh user control view/data binding from another view mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have 2 user controls, representing two views in an MVVM pattern. the view model for the second control is declared as a childViewModel for the view model of the first user control.

I want to update the binding of the 2nd control view and have it refresh/update when the first control receives its data.

I am able to do it if the user control is a separate window (by creating a new instance and passing the new data binding value and using `ShowDialog()`), but as I envisage them as two controls in a single window I need to be able to refresh/update the second view.

How can I update the second view?

Comment: it should be updated since you're binding the control to its viewmodel. what seems not to work?

Comment: there's no change in the view (i've created a fallback value, and it stays there). but if i create a new instance and showDialog() it shows the new value, not the fallback.

Comment: make sure the data context of the control is set to the correct instance. and make sure you are setting the binding path correctly (like {Binding Name} instead of {Binding Child.Name})

Comment: that's exactly the bit i am unsure how to do :) - to reference the existing instance rather than creating a new one

Comment: so the control (at present) just contains a label: <Label Content="{Binding SubmittedQuery, FallbackValue='no url'}" /> so if i wanted it to show in a new window, the following code works just fine: MainBrowserView view = new MainBrowserView();
            view.DataContext = childViewModel;

            childViewModel.SubmittedQuery = Search.Query + "will be submitted.";
            view.ShowDialog(); but i don't know how to change that to update the view/user control within a window using the existing instance. apologies for the formatting - i can't format it or click enter without submitting

Comment: take a look at the answer below. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help you:

```
public class VM1 : DependencyObject
{
    public VM1()
    {
        //as you see the Child is instantiated when VM1 is instantiated
        Child = new VM2();
    }
    public VM2 Child
    {
        get { return (VM2)GetValue(ChildVmProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildVmProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildVmProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Child", typeof(VM2), typeof(VM1), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(VM1), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
public class VM2 : DependencyObject
{
    public string InnerText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(InnerTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InnerTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InnerText", typeof(string), typeof(VM2), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

in the window.xaml:

```
<DockPanel>
    <my:Control1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    <my:Control2 DataContext="{Binding Child}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

but make sure in the window.xaml.cs you set the DataContext correctly:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new VM1();
}
```

now in each control bind to the property name:

Control1.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
</Grid>
```

Control2.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding InnerText}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: so, i don't have a data context in the xaml of the control, i guess this is the first bit i've gone wrong... i'm already initializing a the child along with the parent... (private MainBrowserViewModel  childViewModel; childViewModel = new MainBrowserViewModel();)

Comment: ok... looking at your code in more detail i guess i am going to have to rethink it from the ground up. i don't have any dependencyobject, i just have the VM2 as child of VM1.

Comment: you can either derive your VMs from INotifyPropertyChanged or dependency object (which has more options and is more reliable). I always prefer the second.

Comment: yes i am using inotifypropertychanged. i'm sort of "half" there, because i can create a new instance and show it in a new window and it works fine. what i can't do is get it updating the existing instance in the same window.

Comment: are you doing it like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx